# How to extract partial cypher text with openssl or gpg?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I have edited the question after the clarification of Marcus in his commment.
I have a question and I am unable to find the answer using Google.
 I know that in S/MIME encryption or with GnuPG/Enigmail, the plain text is first encrypted with a symmetric algorithm such as AES or 3DES or IDEA, and the  password used for the symmetric encryption is encrypted with an asymmetric  algorithm (RSA).
 MY question, is possible using gpg or openssl to knows the symmetric algorithm used and do a partial encryption, in other words I would to decrypt only the asymmetric algorithm to view the password used for the symmetric encryption.

I'll try to explain it using math notation :

- T -> plain text
- s -> the symmetric algorithm encryption
- p -> the password used by symmetric encryption function
- a -> the asymmetric encryption function (RSA), it merges cyphered text and other data too.
  k -> my public key

When someone send me a message  I receive C and, since I have my private key, I decrypt it using  it

C =  a(p, k) + s(T, p)

I would to know s(T, p) and p, if possible.

Comment: Not sure if it changes your question, but FYI that's not how it usually works. The resulting cipher text from symmetric encryption is not encrypted using RSA, only the "password" (symmetric key) is encrypted using RSA. The reason for that is that RSA encryption is slow, so the large message is encrypted using symmetric encryption, and then only the encryption key used for that is asymmetrically encrypted.

Comment: You obviously have to define some kind of data format by inserting markers or prepending the length of the following data chunk.

Comment: And PGP and S/MIME in particular do have data formats that separate the recipient key identity, encrypted working key, and encrypted data. PGP uses a fairly simple sequence of packets and `gpg --list-packets $file` will show you what they are, but AFAICT to get the actual data you must parse it yourself as per rfc4880. S/MIME is just CMS/PKCS#7 in (usually) base64 with headers, so you can remove the headers and unbase64 then `openssl asn1parse -inform der` will display the structure and some of the contents, and give you the location (offset and length) to find the rest.